# lsyncd taking time to sync files

Tags: replication, mirroring, lsyncd

`lsyncd` sometimes takes more than 15 minutes to sync file from remote server to local server. Latency is fine, probably process to. What could be the further reasons for late syncing ?

My `lsyncd` config:

```
settings{
 logfile = "/var/log/lsyncd.log",
 statusFile = "/var/log/lsyncd.stat",
 statusInterval = 2,
}
sync{
 default.rsync,
 source="/home/test/",
 target="server.test.local:/home/test",
 rsync={archive = true, perms = true, owner = true, _extra = {"-a"}, rsh ="/usr/bin/ssh -l root -i /root/.ssh/id_rsa",}
}
```

Any kind of help is highly appreciated. Thank you :-)

Comment: How many files in total does `/home/test` have?

Comment: There will be much changes in /home/test directory. But 15 minutes is much longer, right ?

Comment: Number of changes and total number of files are two different things. The replication time depends on the total number of files.

Answer (score 2):

The 'default.rsync' configuration will aggregate events up to `delay` seconds (default: 15) or `maxDelays` separate uncollapsible events (i.e. number of changed files, default: 1000), whichever occurs first.

- To change the synchronization delay, add a `delay = N` parameter to your `sync{}` call.
- To change the number-of-file-changes threshold, add a `maxDelays = N` parameter to your `settings{}` call.
  NB: 'delay`is per-sync while`maxDelays` is global (for all syncs).

lsyncd documentation and variable names are atrocious. `delay` is semi-documented in the 'default.rsync' section at https://axkibe.github.io/lsyncd/manual/config/layer4/ `maxDelays` is documented at https://axkibe.github.io/lsyncd/manual/config/file/